# Trying to access dictionary from a class. Run-time error 91

Tags: vba

I want to use a class, the class should return a dictionary `subjectData` with the keys `name`, `inn`,  `ogrn` and `address` with string values. The code of the class module:

```
'Create dictionary
Public subjectData As Scripting.Dictionary

'Initialize dictionary       
Private Sub class_initalize()
    With subjectData
        .Add "name", ""
        .Add "inn", ""
        .Add "ogrn", ""
        .Add "address", ""
    End With
End Sub
```

When I try to make exemplar of the class in the main module and access it's properties I get runtime error 91 "object variable with block variable not set"

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_New()
  Dim client As New LegalSubject
  client.subjectData.Item(name) = "Microsoft corporation" '<--- Error!
End Sub
```

I figured this is some kind of problem with variable not being `set` to object, but it doesn't work with `set` either. I get "Compile Error: Variable not defined".

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_New()
  Dim client As New LegalSubject
  Set client = LegalSubject
  client.subjectData.Item(name) = "Microsoft corporation"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the real name of `Initialize` event of a `Class` is `Class_Initialize()`

2) in the `Initialize` event you have to set the dictionary object before using it

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set subjectData = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With subjectData
        .Add "name", ""
        .Add "inn", ""
        .Add "ogrn", ""
        .Add "address", ""
    End With
End Sub
```